# How change http resposne status for custom FormRequest?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use the following class to validate incoming request:

```
class CreateInvoiceRequest extends FormRequest
{

    public function authorize(Request $request)
    {
        return true;

    }

    public function messages()
    {
        return [
            'name.required' => 'The name is required.',
            'name.string' => 'The name should be a string',
            'code.required' => 'Code',
              'code.string' => 'Code',
              'type.required' => 'Type'
        ];
    }

    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|string',
            'type' => 'string',
            'code' => ['required', 'string', new InvoiceCode],
        ];
    }
}
```

In fail case it returns data in `{errors: "The given data was invalid."}` object and http status 200.

How and where to change this status? More global question, how to handle errors and warnings in Laravel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add an HTTP status to the [`ValidationException`](https://laravel.com/api/5.8/Illuminate/Validation/ValidationException.html) thrown in the [`failedValidation`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php#L128) method of FormRequest:

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator;
use Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException;

class CreateInvoiceRequest extends FormRequest
{
    // ...

    protected function failedValidation(Validator $validator)
    {
        throw (new ValidationException($validator))
                    ->status(500)
                    ->errorBag($this->errorBag)
                    ->redirectTo($this->getRedirectUrl());
    }

    // ...

}
```

Comment: How to import `ValidationException`?

Comment: Imports added. `$this->errorBag` is part of the parent class [FormRequest](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.8/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/FormRequest.php).

Comment: How to throw exception from this class to global exception `class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {}`?

Comment: You call `throw (new ValidationException($validator))` it returns data to browser immidiatly, but I need catch it in global Handler

Comment: I know, but I need throw exception in `CreateInvoiceRequest` but catch it in `class Handler extends ExceptionHandler {}`

Comment: Then create a custom exception and replace `ValidationException` with it.